# TeXStudio XeLaTeX font not found using package, works on other computer

Tags: fonts

**EDIT: If anyone has the same problem, I ended up deleting my editors as well as TexLive, and installed MikTex. Fixed the issue.**

I am using `XeLaTex` and want to use the package [CharisSIL](https://ctan.org/pkg/charissil) to display IPA characters.

> \usepackage{CharisSIL}

On my computer, I always get the following error:

> File `CharisSIL.sty' not found. \usepackage

If I use the same document on another computer, then the document compiles without problem. Note that I have installed manually the font, but it didn't solve the problem (and it is not installed in the computer where it works).

EDIT:

preamble.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{CharisSIL}
% Line Spacing 1.0
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
%(1.0*2355/2048)/(14.5/12) = 0.95164331896
\setstretch{1}
% Margins = 2.5cm
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=gray,
    citecolor=gray,
}
```

main.tex

```
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
    
    \input{titlepage}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \input{intro}
    \input{prob}
    \input{etat}
    \input{sources}
    \input{metho}
    \input{calendrier}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    
    %\bibliography{bib} 
    %\bibliographystyle{apacite}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Otherwise we have no idea what exactly you are doing

Comment: For example, what exactly did you mean by `I have installed manually the font`? Why wasn't it installed via your LaTeX installation?

Comment: Added an example. I mean that since the error is file not found, I went on the CharisSIL website, downloaded the .ttf files and installed them on my machine. I do not know why it doesn't work using only the package, which should be the case as it works on another computer with the exact sames files (minus the .ttf installation)

Comment: `tlmgr info CharisSIL.sty` reports it is in the `charissil` package so if using texlive you probably need `tlmgr install charissil`

Comment: installing the _font_ will not make the _tex_ file `CharisSIL.sty` be installed.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but I get the following message:
 tlmgr.pl install: package already present: charissil